# Преобразование строки в математическое выражение Python не используя eval

Tags: python, строки, математика

У меня есть строка: "10/2-4"

Как преобразовать данную строку в математическое выражение?

То есть есть функция f:
`def f(string):`
Нужно чтобы она вывела результат, при этом не используя **eval**

Так же функция должна именно **возвращать** используя return

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_рекурсивного_спуска и есть ещё такое https://habr.com/ru/post/494316/

Comment: _при этом не используя eval_ уточните пожлуйста, а что можно  использовать?

Comment: Что-то сложные методы тут предлагают. В свое время справился с такой задачей путем преобразования выражения в постфиксную нотацию и дальше посчитал выражение с помощью нее.  
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Comment: Такое впечатление, что людей поголовно забанили в гугле. Казалось бы, первое, что нужно сделать - поискать "python expression parser" и разобраться.

Comment: 0xdb, использовать можно все кроме eval и функцию print. Функция должна именно возвращать результат используя return